# Is changing image "src" attribute with JS bad practice?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, httprequest

If I had HTML like this:

`<img id="img1" src="picture1.jpg" />`

and I used JS (jQuery in this example) to switch the image source on a particular action, like this:

`jQuery('#img1').attr('src','picture2.jpg')`

thereby forcing the browser to send a new request to the server and fetch the new image, would that be considered bad practice, and if so, why? Please do not post just your opinion (unless you're an all-star), it would be good to have a reputable source. Thanks!

Comment: If you need to load a new image, that's a perfectly OK thing to do. There's not going to be any "source" that says this is OK because it's so innocuous that it's unlikely anybody's bothered to explicitly bless it.

Comment: Have you read something that suggests it's *not* OK?

Comment: What do you consider a `reputable source`?

Comment: `jQuery('#img1').attr('src','picture2.jpg')` can be just `img1.src="picture2.jpg'`, and while explicit ID globals are not preferred, setting the property instead of the attribute is. my point is to set the .src instead of using setAttribute()-style alterations.

Answer (score 3):

No. It's fine. Go for it!

You browser will only make a new request to the server if the image is not cached yet. As soon the image is cached the browser will look at the cache before go for a new request!